# Calling method of child class on a vector of parent class

Tags: c++, oop, vector, polymorphism, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Parent {
public:
    Parent();
    void method();
};

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    Child();
    void method();
};

int main() {
    vector<Parent> v;
    v.push_back(Parent());
    v.push_back(Child());
    v[0].method();
    v[1].method();
    return 0;
}

Parent::Parent() {}

void Parent::method() {
    cout << "Parent." << endl;
}

Child::Child() {}

void Child::method() {
    cout << "Child." << endl;
}
```

Basically I'd expect that program to print

```
Parent.
Child.
```

but it prints this instead:

```
Parent.
Parent.
```

C++ surprises me yet again :).
Why does this happen? What can I do to call Child::method for instances of Child in the vector, and Parent::method for instances of Parent?

I'm using gcc:

```
gcc version 4.6.1 20110819 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

like this:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -c main.cpp
g++ -Wall -Wextra -o main main.o
```

Comment: @Tomalak: I did search. A lot. But how am I supposed to know this is called "slicing"? :/

Comment: Searching for `parent child vector c++` would probably do it.

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, I didn't think this was a common problem, and maybe thought that was a bit far-fetched. But point taken, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encountering the *slicing problem*.

`vector<Parent>.push_back()` *copies* its argument, so it invokes `Parent::Parent(const Parent &)` (i.e. the copy constructor)<sup>*</sup>.

This is really no different to:

```
Parent x[10];

x[0] = Parent();
x[1] = Child();
```

<sub>* Or it might be `Parent::operator=(const Parent &)`, i.e. copy-assignment.  I'm tired, and I can't remember which it needs.</sub>

Comment: @Oli: I don't think that it's specified, actually. Placement new would be required for copy construction; initial default construction would be required for copy assignment. So I'd say a sane implementation will usually do the former.

Comment: `n3290: 23.2.1/13` describes `CopyInsertable`ness, which is the only requirement. And it says that the default allocator will use placement `new`, but that others may not.

Answer (score 0):

The vector stores `Parent`s, not `Children`s.

If you want to take advantage of polymorphism, store pointers instead... but be damned sure that it's what you want.

Comment: This isn't really going to address the issue yet as `method` isn't `virtual`.

Comment: @pmr: Indeed, there is more work to be done. However, I did not write my answer intending for it to be a 25-page book chapter on polymorphism. The OP can look up that chapter in his own book for the full story.

Comment: @Gerardo That's what I have been saying. Your member functions need to be `virtual`. Tomalak is of course right: You need to read a book.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak and @pmr , this helped a lot.